# jQuery stylesheet wont load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright! So I got a jQuery sheet in "borrowing" from another page. The jQuery works fine with the code that links it to the original location.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://restaurantleduc.com/wp-content/themes/leduc/js/LD.js"></script>
```

However, when I try to export the whole code from the original website it wont work for me. Not in my script and not in an stylesheet for itself...  Could really use some help on this one . :) Here is the original "raw" code:

```js
if ( !window.$ ) window.$ = window.jQuery;

// Create Namespace
var LD = window.LD || {};

/* EVENT MANAGER */
LD.EM = LD.EM || $({});

/*
 * EVENTS
 */
LD.Events = {
    APP_READY  : "APP_READY",
    SCROLLED  : "SCROLLED",
    RESIZED  : "RESIZED"
};

// VARS-CONST
LD.WIDTH = 0;
LD.HEIGHT = 0;

$(window).ready(function(){

 $("html").addClass( (LD.Utils.hasTouch() ? "touch" : "no-touch") );

 LD.Resize.init();
 LD.Scroll.init();
 LD.Menu.init();
 LD.Carousel.init();
 LD.Footer.init();

 if ( $(".home").length )
  LD.Home.init();

 if ( $(".news").length )
  LD.News.init();
});

$(window).load(function() {
 $(window).trigger("resize");
 $(window).trigger("scroll");
});


LD.Utils = {

 hasTouch : function() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window;
 },

 isValidEmailAddress : function (emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
 },

 map : function(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2) {
  return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1));
 },

 createCookie : function(name,value,days) {

  var expires = "";
  if (days) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
 },

 readCookie : function(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
   var c = ca[i];
   while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
   if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
 },

 eraseCookie : function(name) {
  LD.Utils.createCookie(name,"",-1);
 }
};

LD.Carousel = LD.Carousel ||Â {

 sliders : [],

 init : function() {

  if ( $(".article-carousel").length === 0 ) return;
  this.initSwipe();
 },

 initSwipe : function() {

  var self = this;
  $(".article-carousel .swipe").each( function( i, swipe ) {

   var slider = new Swipe(swipe, {
    speed: 900,
    continuous: true,
    callback : $.proxy( self.callbackSlider, self )
   });

   $(swipe).parents(".article-preview").data("index", i);

   self.sliders.push( slider );
  });

  imagesLoaded( $('body'), function() {
   LD.EM.trigger( LD.Events.RESIZED );
  });


  $(".btn-next, .btn-prev", ".article-carousel").on("click", $.proxy( this.navSwipe, this ));
  $(".btn-dot", ".article-carousel").on("click", $.proxy( this.dotSwipe, this ));
 },

 callbackSlider : function(index, el) {
  
  var 
   $el = $(el),
   $parent = $el.parents(".article-preview, .article-full"),
   sliderIndex = $parent.data("index") || 0,
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  $(".btn-dot.selected", $parent).removeClass("selected");
  $(".btn-dot:eq(" + slider.getPos() + ")", $parent).addClass("selected");
 },

 navSwipe : function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var 
   $el = $(e.currentTarget),
   sliderIndex = $el.parents(".article-preview").data("index") ||Â 0,
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  if ( $el.hasClass("btn-prev") ) {
   slider.prev();
  } else {
   slider.next();
  }
 },

 dotSwipe : function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var 
   $el = $(e.currentTarget),
   sliderIndex = $el.parents(".article-preview").data("index") ||Â 0,
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  slider.slide( $el.data("index") );
 }
};

LD.Footer = LD.Footer ||Â {

 init : function() {

  this.initBtn();
  this.initNewsletter();
 },

 initBtn : function() {

  $("footer .btn-top").on("click", $.proxy( this.onTopClick, this ));
 },

 onTopClick : function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop : 0
  }, 1200);
 },

 initNewsletter : function () {

  var 
   $context = $("footer"),
   email;

  $(".form-newsletter", $context).on("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $(".valid-error, .post-error, .valid", $context).hide();

   email = $(".form-email", this).val();
   if ( LD.Utils.isValidEmailAddress(email) ) {

    $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function() {
     $(".valid", $context).show();
    })
    .fail(function() {
     $(".post-error", $context).show();
    });
    
   } else {
    $(".valid-error", $context).show();
   }
  
  });
 },
};

LD.Menu = LD.Menu ||Â {

 init : function() {

  this.initLang();
 },

 initLang : function() {

  var newlang;
  $(".btn-lang").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   newlang = $(this).data("lang");
   LD.Utils.eraseCookie("leduc_lang");
   LD.Utils.createCookie("leduc_lang", newlang, 365);
   window.location.reload();
  });
 }

};


LD.Resize = LD.Resize ||Â {

 init : function() {

  LD.WIDTH = $(window).width();
  LD.HEIGHT = $(window).height();

  $(window).on("resize", $.proxy(this.onResize, this));
 },

 kill : function() {

  $(window).off("resize", $.proxy(this.onResize, this));
 },

 onResize : function() {

  LD.WIDTH = $(window).width();
  LD.HEIGHT = $(window).height();
  
  LD.EM.trigger( LD.Events.RESIZED );
 }
};

LD.Scroll = LD.Scroll ||Â {

 $body : null,
 $carte : null,
 $lunch : null,
 $starters : null,
 $mains : null,
 $restaurant : null,
 
 scrollPos : null,
 scrollLunch : null,
 scrollStarters : null,
 scrollMains : null,
 scrollRestaurant : null,

 init : function() {

  this.$body = $("body");

  this.$carte = $(".home-carte");
  this.$lunch = $(".block-lunch");
  this.$starters = $(".block-starters");
  this.$mains = $(".block-mains");

  this.$restaurant = $(".home-restaurant");

  this.onResized();
  LD.EM.on( LD.Events.RESIZED, $.proxy( this.onResized, this ) );
  $(window).on("scroll", $.proxy(this.onScroll, this));
 },

 kill : function() {

  $(window).off("scroll", $.proxy(this.onScroll, this));
 },

 onResized : function() {

  if ( this.$carte.length === 0 ) return;

  var 
   offset = Math.round(LD.HEIGHT*0.5),
   offsetTopCarte = this.$carte.position().top;

  this.scrollLunch = offsetTopCarte - offset;
  this.scrollStarters = offsetTopCarte + this.$starters.position().top - offset - 150;
  this.scrollMains = offsetTopCarte + this.$mains.position().top - offset - 150;

  this.scrollRestaurant = this.$restaurant.position().top - offset;
 },

 onScroll : function() {

  this.checkScroll( 128, this.$body, "sticky" );
  
  if ( !LD.Utils.hasTouch() ) {
   this.checkScroll( this.scrollLunch, this.$lunch, "show-lunch" );
   this.checkScroll( this.scrollStarters, this.$starters, "show-starters" );
   this.checkScroll( this.scrollMains, this.$mains, "show-mains" );

   this.checkScroll( this.scrollRestaurant, this.$restaurant, "show-restaurant" );
  }
  
  LD.EM.trigger( LD.Events.SCROLLED );
 },

 checkScroll : function( limit, $el, className ) {

  var currentScrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  LD.scrollPos = currentScrollPos;

  if ( currentScrollPos > limit ) {
   $el.addClass(className);
  } else {
   $el.removeClass(className);
  }
 }
};

LD.Home = LD.Home ||Â {

 $sliders : null,
 sliders : [],

 init : function() {

  this.$sliders = $(".swipe-container");

  this.initMenu();
  this.initSliders();
  this.initCarte();

  // GOOGLE MAPS
  this.initMap();

  LD.EM.on( LD.Events.SCROLLED, $.proxy( this.onScrolled, this ) );
  LD.EM.on( LD.Events.RESIZED, $.proxy( this.onResized, this ) );
 },

 initMenu : function () {

  $(".logo a").on("click", function(e) {
   
   if ( $(".home").length ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
   }
  });

  $("a.btn-internal").on("click", function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var target = $(this).attr("href").replace("/", "");

   $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( target ).offset().top - 110
   }, 1000);
  });
 },

 initSliders : function() {

  var self = this;

  $(".swipe").each( function( i, swipe ) {

   var slider = new Swipe(swipe, {
    auto : 6000,
    speed: 900,
    continuous: true,
    callback : $.proxy( self.callbackSlider, self )
   });

   self.sliders.push( slider );
  });

  $(".btn-next, .btn-prev").on("click", $.proxy( this.navSwipe, this ));
  $(".btn-dot").on("click", $.proxy( this.dotSwipe, this ));
 },

 navSwipe : function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var 
   $el = $(e.currentTarget),
   sliderIndex = $el.parents(".swipe-container").data("index"),
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  if ( $el.hasClass("btn-prev") ) {
   slider.prev();
  } else {
   slider.next();
  }
 },

 dotSwipe : function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var 
   $el = $(e.currentTarget),
   sliderIndex = $el.parents(".swipe-container").data("index"),
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  slider.slide( $el.data("index") );
 },

 callbackSlider : function( index, el ) {

  var 
   $el = $(el),
   $parent = $el.parents(".swipe-container"),
   sliderIndex = $parent.data("index"),
   slider = this.sliders[ sliderIndex ];

  $(".btn-dot.selected", $parent).removeClass("selected");
  $(".btn-dot:eq(" + slider.getPos() + ")", $parent).addClass("selected");
 },

 initMap : function() {

  var 
   $el = $(".map"),
   center = new google.maps.LatLng( $el.data("lat"), $el.data("lng") ),

   mapOptions = {
    scrollwheel : false,
    disableDefaultUI : true,
    center: center,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles : [{"featureType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":0},{"hue":"#e7ecf0"}]},{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"saturation":-70}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":-60}]}]
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], mapOptions);

     new google.maps.Marker({
   "position": center,
   "map": map
  });
 },

 initCarte : function() {

  this.$carteWrap = $(".home-carte");
  this.$carteHeight = this.$carteWrap.height();
  this.$carteTop = this.$carteWrap.position().top;
  this.$fishes = $(".fish", this.$carteWrap);
 },

 onScrolled : function() {

  if ( LD.Utils.hasTouch() ) return;

  if ( this.$carteTop < LD.scrollPos + LD.HEIGHT && this.$carteTop + this.$carteHeight > LD.scrollPos ) {
   
   var 
    val = this.$carteTop - (LD.scrollPos + LD.HEIGHT),
    max = this.$carteHeight + LD.HEIGHT,
    p = LD.Utils.map( val, 0, max, 0, 150 ),
    $fish = null;

   this.$fishes.each(function (i, fish) {

    $fish = $(fish);
    $fish.css("transform", "translateY(" + (p * $fish.data("speed")) + "%)");
   });
  }
 },

 onResized : function() {

 }
};

LD.News = LD.News ||Â {

 init : function() {

  this.initBtnTop();
 },

 initBtnTop : function() {

  $(".btn-top").on("click", $.proxy(this.toTop, this));
 },

 toTop : function() {

  $("html, body").animate({
   "scrollTop" : 0
  }, 300);
 }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "stylesheet"? Also, "it doesn't work" is not nearly accurate enough...

Comment: There is way too much information here. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking the jquery library? If you don't want to download and host it yourself you can use the link below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```